# RESTful Shopping Cart web service

Tags: web-services, rest, shopping-cart

I was wondering if someone has successfully implemented a RESTful Shopping Cart Web service. I am perticularly interested in Production level implementation rather than test app.

Would there be any advantage in this approch rather than SOAP-style?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I haven't. I would be completely astonished if somewhere in the world "someone" has  not. I know of plenty of equivalently important RESTful services running in production or production ready. As an example one of my employer, IBM's, flagship products WebSphere Process Server, exposes [restful services](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6r2mx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.bspace.620.help.api.rest.doc/apis/wsprocessserver/index.htm).

I'm guessing that you are asking the question from the perspective that suspects that RESTful services are not yet mature. My experience is that because of their relative simplicity the support stack for such services reached maturity quite quickly. In the Java world JAX/RS is very easy to use and seems to me to be very stable.

Advantages: Simplicity, really easy to consume from JavaScript, especially with JSON payloads, potential for much simpler life-cycles and versioning than with WSDL.

Disadvantages: the more advanced WS-* capabilties are not available as standard.